# PHP PayPal Error - MALFORMED_REQUEST - Incoming JSON request does not map to API request

Tags: php, json, api, rest, paypal

I have an error using the PayPal REST API but I can't find a solution anywhere. I'm trying to send the user to PayPal to pay for the specified items in a session array. I have tried changing the payment method, the intent and the URLs.

```
    $this->setupCurl();
    $this->setupPayPal();

    $this->payer = new Payer();
    $this->details = array();
    $this->amount = array();
    $this->transaction = array();
    $this->redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $this->payment = new Payment();

    $this->payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal'); // TODO paypal . credit_card

    foreach ($cart as $id => $item) {
        $this->details[$id] = new Details();
        $this->amount[$id] = new Amount();
        $this->transaction[$id] = new Transaction();

        $this->details[$id]->setShipping('0.00')
                      ->setTax('0.00')
                      ->setSubtotal(formatMoney($this->products[$id]['price'] * $item['quantity'], '', 2)); // TODO

        $this->amount[$id]->setCurrency('AUD')
                     ->setTotal(formatMoney($this->products[$id]['price'] * $item['quantity'], '', 2))
                     ->setDetails($this->details[$id]);

        $this->transaction[$id]->setAmount($this->amount[$id])
                          ->setDescription($this->products[$id]['name']); // TODO
    }

    $this->redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('https://warsentech.com/pay?approved=true')
                       ->setCancelUrl('https://warsentech.com/pay?approved=false');

    $this->payment->setIntent('authorize') // TODO sale . buy
                  ->setPayer($this->payer)
                  ->setRedirectUrls($this->redirectUrls)
                  ->setTransactions($this->transaction); // TODO - add transactions into array from the cart items

    try {
        $this->payment->create($this->paypal);

        $hash = md5($this->payment->getId());
        $_SESSION['paypal_hash'] = $hash;
        if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
            $result = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO transactions_paypal (user_id, payment_id, hash, complete) VALUES (:user_id, :payment_id, :hash, 0)');
            $result->execute([
                'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
                'payment_id' => $this->payment->getId(),
                'hash' => $hash
            ]);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die(paypalError($e));
    }

    foreach ($this->payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        if ($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
            $redirectUrl = $link->getHref();
        }
    }
```

Full error message:

> exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in /var/www/html/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:177 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(74): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"auth...') #1 /var/www/html/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(103): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"auth...', NULL) #2 /var/www/html/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php(424): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"auth...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), NULL) #3 /var/www/html/classes/PayPal.php(168): PayPal\Api\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext)) #4 /var/www/html/classes/PayPal.php(50): PayPal->pay(Array) #5 /var/www/html/checkout.php(39): PayPal->__construct() #6 {main}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I would recommend to fix this issue:

1. From the error message you saw that the error you are seeing is of type `PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException`. We have a special method `getData()` to retrieve the exact details about the error.

You can do that by doing something like this:

```
try {
    $this->payment->create($this->paypal);

    $hash = md5($this->payment->getId());
    $_SESSION['paypal_hash'] = $hash;
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        $result = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO transactions_paypal (user_id, payment_id, hash, complete) VALUES (:user_id, :payment_id, :hash, 0)');
        $result->execute([
            'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
            'payment_id' => $this->payment->getId(),
            'hash' => $hash
        ]);
    }
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e) {
    echo $e->getData(); // This will print a JSON which has specific details about the error.
    die(paypalError($e));
}
```

2. If you are looking to get some help integrating our SDK, there are lot of documents that could help you. Here are the most interesting one you should be looking at:

   - Samples demonstrating each API operations : http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/
   - How to run these samples in local machine by one command: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples
   - Wiki Pages explaining how to get started with our APIs: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki

And specifically, you should be looking at this sample that demonstrate exactly what you are trying to do: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

Let me know if this helps figure out the issue you are facing.